# Getting response from form post method in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, post

I'm trying to get the response from a POST method using a form so I can redirect the user to another website when it's submitted. The problem is I can't figure out how to get response from the method because I need the data to do other things. This is the code that I have in my component:

```
import React from 'react'

function PagarCoinPayments() {
    return (
        <div className="container d-flex justify-content-center h-100 align-items-center">
            <div className="card text-center bg-dark col-md-4 animate__animated animate__fadeInUp">
                <img src="" alt=""/> 
                <div className="card-body text-light"> 
                    <h4 className="card-title ">Confirmación de pago</h4>
                    <br/>
                    <h6 className="card-title ">Nombre y Apellido: John Doe</h6>
                    <br/>
                    <h6 className="card-title ">Cédula: 27.000.000</h6>
                    <br/>
                    <h6 className="card-title ">Descripción: 5 materias, mes de octubre</h6>
                    <br/>
                    <h6 className="card-title ">Monto: 375 USDT</h6>
                    
                    </div>
                        <form action="https://www.coinpayments.net/index.php" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_pay_simple"></input>
                            <input type="hidden" name="reset" value="1"></input>
                            <input type="hidden" name="merchant" value="XXX"></input>
                            <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="5 materias, mes de octubre"></input>
                            <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USDT"></input>
                            <input type="hidden" name="amountf" value="5"></input>
                            <input type="hidden" name="want_shipping" value="0"></input>
                            <input type="image" src="https://www.coinpayments.net/images/pub/buynow-grey.png" alt="Comprar ahora con CoinPayments.net"></input>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                    <br/>
                <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default PagarCoinPayments
```

Comment: You can use AJAX for doing this. Try using [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#supplying_request_options) or the [Axios Library](https://github.com/axios/axios#example). Here is a [YouTube video to get you started](https://youtu.be/T3Px88x_PsA?list=PLN3n1USn4xlntqksY83W3997mmQPrUmqM)